# Android Studio Emulator is already running but nothing shows up

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run my android studio code but the emulator does not run. It keeps showing this error

[image: Error]

and I cant delete the files because they're still running. When I run it the first time, it will timeout after 300s after waiting for the emulator to come online and subsequently give the error above.

I've tried various methods such as ending tasks, deleting the files, changing the API but it still would not run. The emulator does not even show up and I cant stop the avd either. I've even uninstalled it multiple times... I'm getting very desperate as this is for a school project. Please help, thanks in advance.
as you can see the device is running but there is no screen shown.

[image]

Update:
I found out that the reason for this is because whenever the emulator runs, it doesnt respond at all, hence it will not close and continue running.... How do I fix this...

Comment: Did you try restarting Android Studio?

Comment: If you mean closing the app and opening it again then yes.

Comment: If you restarted Android studio, then you can delete the emulator and create a new one.

Comment: I've tried creating multiple AVDs already but they all turn out the same. Apparently the emulator doesn't respond whenever it runs